# Is it bad design to use json_encode data instead of creating new table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have an order and each order has some product related to it. I want to save name, price, and short description for each product.

I know that the normal approach is create two tables, `orders` and `products`, but **what if I do not need to query for products specifically?** Is it OK to `json_encode` products on the order object with PHP and save it as a column on the `orders` table in mysql?

Comment: imagine if you wanted to query for products in the future....

Comment: How do people place orders if they can't see product?

Comment: For an RDBMS (which is designed to deal with information), the only case when such really "isn't bad" is when it is *truly opaque data* (think of the contents of a binary file) - that is, it will *never* be searched, *never* be partially updated/read, *never* participate in any relationship. It exists merely as an opaque blob of data (not information). In this particular case, because those "never"s are something that is desired it "is bad" - eg. you *want* the DRI relationships, you *want* to be able to query. So just use the RDBMs correctly and move on..

Comment: `Is it okay?` is extremely subjective and conditional. Have you tried? What was the result? Were there downsides?

Comment: Consider the other uses you'd use a separate table for: Average number of items per order, count on number of stock that need to be ordered of a specific item, etc. There are a number of uses for having the products for an order in their own table. The only reason not is an attempt to make it easier to code (which will cause more problems in the end).

Comment: You will need a table for products either way, so creating this redundancy is pointless and a good example of what not to do with databases.

Comment: *"I want to save name, price, and short description for each product."* Think about where that data will come from. Will it come from you, or will it come from the user? (Personally, I quite *like* the idea of being able to input the price for things I order.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is consistently structured (which it sounds like it is), you should create a table.

JSON or other serialized formats are good for data that is inconsistent.

It is convenient to store the product info right on the order (which is part of the appeal of NoSQL databases), but unless that data structure differs between products, you are best to follow the standard of creating the data in a relational way.

---

Use case where JSON would be helpful:

Let's say you were tracking an event stream that had information about the events before checkout. You might want to store data that isn't stored consistently. You might store the following to an `order_analytics` column on the `orders` table.

```
{
    type: "page_visited",
    data: {
        url: "/example/1",
        title: "Example Page"
    }
},
{
    type: "added_to_cart",
    data: {
        product_id: 4,
        product_name: "Example Product"
    }
},
{
    type: "removed_from_cart",
    data: {
        product_id: 4,
        product_name: "Example Product"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

As you state that you "do not need to query for product", you could `serialize()` your data and `unserialize()` it on read, it's pretty common usage and perfectly valid practice. It won't be JSON, but you can easily convert it to JSON after `unserialize()`.

Comment: This is just an alternative to json-encoding, but it isn't the question he is asking. He is asking if it makes sense to serialize data and store it on a single column as opposed to storing it on a second table.

Comment: Actually he's asking if he could store the data in plain JSON string format, which he could if he wanted, too. I don't see why not, if that data is static and will never change. Right?

Comment: Of course he could. He specifically said "Is it bad design" though, indiciating that he was asking if it is a best practice, not if it is possible.

Comment: He asked, not stated. It is not bad design, you can store a JSON string in a blob and use it as desired, it's perfectly valid and a good approach to store already processed data that will not ever change.